# How to set query timeout less than 1 second at Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, timeout

I use Hibernate 5.4.1.Final and Java 8. I set query timeout to a TypedQuery by

```
typedQuery.setHint("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 400);
```

But hibernate converts it to seconds and rounds down to 0. When I get hints

```
typedQuery.getHints();
{org.hibernate.timeout=0, javax.persistence.query.timeout=0}
```

If I set sth over 500 it rounds up to 1 seconds.

```
typedQuery.setHint("javax.persistence.query.timeout", 500);
typedQuery.getHints();
{org.hibernate.timeout=1, javax.persistence.query.timeout=1000}
```

How can we set query timeout with milliseconds and less than 1 second?

Thank you.

Comment: My guess is that internally, Hibernate uses the hint with the `org.hibernate.Query.setTimeout()` method, which has second granularity. You should probably register a bug with Hibernate folks

Comment: @crizzis thanks for your answer. I hoped if there is a workaround but it looks grim when we check the source code. https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/annotations/QueryHintDefinition.java

I don't know how all hibernate users manage this. There should be a way...

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate doesn’t handle this timeout itself but provides it to the JDBC driver via the JDBC Statement.setTimeout method. (see: https://thoughts-on-java.org/11-jpa-hibernate-query-hints-every-developer-know/)

Also see this issue https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=456067 .

It seems that Hibernate might be forced to convert this value to seconds whenever the JDBC driver only offers to specify seconds for this configuration. Please check the timeout accuracy offered by your JDBC driver. It might very well be the expected behaviour.

Network timeouts seem to be more appropriate if specified in seconds anyway, because of random network delays which are hard to avoid.

Comment: Thank you. Yes you're right JDBC forces the parameter in seconds. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout-int-

I thought it's in milliseconds because "javax.persistence.query.timeout" parameter is in milliseconds. So, it seems there is no way to make it in milliseconds. I'm really surprised :) 1 second is a very long duration in 2019. :)

Comment: I don't know. We do have very fast networks today - yes - but how can you be sure that all your database queries can be processed within 500 ms? There are many - yet rare - situations when your DB server might just pause for a few seconds. (schema update, backup, table lock)

Answer (score 1):

We find a workaround by setting **statement_timeout** parameter of Postgresql DB. When we need to limit the query execution time, we execute the following script. Sure timeout value is configurable. After running the query we set this parameter to 0.

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
session.doWork(new Work() {

    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        connection.createStatement().execute("set statement_timeout = 300");
    }
});
```

Comment: so, you are switching timeouts between 6 minutes and none at all, right?

Comment: No it's in milliseconds. @Mick

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact issue, after debugging **(a lot)** hibernate and my (maria-db) JDBC connector.

I noticed this **code line below** (in hibernate-core) which basically forces you to use seconds in MS format (e.g. 1000) for hint 'javax.persistence.query.timeout' otherwise, it will round the value (value is the hint's value)

Which basically means you can't have 1-999 milliseconds but 0 or 1 seconds

```
int timeout = (int)Math.round( ConfigurationHelper.getInteger( value ).doubleValue() / 1000.0 );
```

[Code line was taken from this source code](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/query/internal/AbstractProducedQuery.java#L1026)

I hope you find a solution since I couldn't find a workaround

**EDIT:**

The only way I could pull this off was using connection's network timeout.

Please be aware that since this is done **"manually"** no clean up will be done for you as does hibernate does (closing/ releasing resources) nor won't call KILL command you would have to do it on **your own**

```
int timeoutMs = 250;
var connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
connection.setNetworkTimeout(Runnable::run, timeoutMs);
var callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call testSp()}");
// Setup your SP parameters
callableStatement.execute();
```

Comment: You can see the workaround at my below post. We decided to set the timeout at DB level. I think this is what we really want to do. I don't know MariaDB but the below code worked well at Postgresql. I believe MariaDB has an option to set the statement timeout.

Comment: In Maria DB max statement time at DB level exists but it's in seconds as seen in official docs https://mariadb.com/kb/en/server-system-variables/#max_statement_time so this won't help...

Answer (score 0):

To set a timeout for Hibernate-managed query in milliseconds, you have to obtain a full control of a Hibernate-managed JDBC Connection (and, no, you are not locked with plain JDBC instead of Hibernate).

One way to do it is to implement your own `ConnectionProvider`. As usual, you would like to subclass your current `ConnectionProvider`, suppose it is stock `DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl`, and override just two methods: `getConnection()` and `closeConnection(Connection)`.

```
public class MillisConnectionProvider extends DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl {

    private final ConcurrentMap<Connection, Integer> alteredConnections = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();    

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        final Connection connection = super.getConnection();
        alteredConnections.put(connection, connection.getNetworkTimeout());
        connection.setNetworkTimeout(Runnable :: run, myTimeoutInMilliseconds);
        return connection;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void closeConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        connection.setNetworkTimeout(Runnable :: run, alteredConnections.remove(connection));
        super.closeConnection(connection);
    }
    
}
```

As `Connection` is conceptually stateless thing and therefore should and will be reused it is necessary to store its initial timeout in a `ConcurrentMap`, then restore the timeout upon `Connection` closing. The `Executor`, chosen for timeout setting, is a plain caller, we don't need anything more sophisticated.

Multithreading issues: `alteredConnections` has be thread-safe as the `ConnectionProvider` is, of course, accessed simultaneously by multiple threads in an application, but no more guarding is necessary as a `Connection` is not shared between threads by Hibernate.

Next, we have to register our custom `ConnectionProvider` with Hibernate. As of version 5.3.9 it can be done with appropriate `ServiceContributor` implementation:

```
public class MillisConnectionProviderServiceContributor implements ServiceContributor {
    
    @Override
    public void contribute(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder) {
        serviceRegistryBuilder.addService(ConnectionProvider.class, new MillisConnectionProviderServiceContributor());
    }

}
```

, then it should be registered in `META-INF/services/org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator` classpath resource:

```
com.foo.MillisConnectionProviderServiceContributor
```

Another good question is how to define the `myTimeoutInMilliseconds` as it most likely would have been set per Hibernate query, Criteria, etc. There is no easy solution to this problem as at the level of `ConnectionProvider` there is no access to these instances. The only easy thing I can think of is to use `ThreadLocal`: inject `myTimeoutInMilliseconds` value into the thread storage and retrieve it at the level of `ConnectionProvider` (don't forget to clean the state of the `ThreadLocal` upon closing a `Connection`).

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
typedQuery.setHint("org.hibernate.timeout", "1");
typedQuery.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: How exactly does this help in obtaining the query timeout of 400 ms?

Comment: Sry i understood another thing